# syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".c")

Tags: shell, shell-script, bourne-shell

I am trying to test if file "file1.c" is present in the current working directory, what am I doing wrong with my test command? I thought I understood this command, am I doing something wrong for the Bourne shell that I do not know about?

```
#! /bin/sh
NAME=$1
if((test -e "$NAME"));then
echo File $NAME present
else
echo File $NAME not present
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the enclosing parentheses, `test` itself would suffice:

```
if test -e "$NAME"; then
```

The `(())` is for arithmetic comparison operations.

`test` is synonymous to `[` command, so you can use:

```
if [ -e "$NAME" ]; then
```

too.

Also some shell has the `[[` keyword:

```
if [[ -e "$NAME" ]]; then
```

Comment: Thank you. That works for me. Is this only for test? Because I am able to do something like if(($# != 2));then....and the parentheses is required for me (or atleast it doesn't work without it).

Comment: @AndrewM Check my edits..

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My book does not cover this well at all.